# Is the phrase 僕も私も used in ordinary speech?

Tags: words

It seems common in advertising, but is it used in speech?

Comment: I have to say it depends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's commonly used in everyday conversations. To say 'we all', we usually use 我々みんな, 僕たち全員, etc., depending on the formality.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask if it is commonly used in ordinary speech, the answer is no, but I don't think it sounds particularly weird to use that phrase in ordinary speech. I just can't think of a situation where I would say "I" twice like that in an ordinary context.